# python list comprehension does not work correctly

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to write method which will return a word from file based on passed argument. But if there is no words which fit the argument I want to return nothing. So in my file, the highest word has 97points. But if I pass score 98, error about index is displayed. I have something like this:

main.py

```
from option import Option
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group.add_argument( "--score", "-s", help="Find word for given score", type=int)

option = Option()
if args.score:
    option.word_from_score(args.score)
```

option.py

```
import random
class Option():
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = [line.rstrip('\n').upper() for line in open('dictionary.txt', "r")] 

    SCRABBLES_SCORES = [(1, "E A O I N R T L S U"), (2, "D G"), (3, "B C M P"),
                (4, "F H V W Y"), (5, "K"), (8, "J X"), (10, "Q Z"), (11, "Ą Ć Ę Ł Ń Ó Ś Ź Ż")]
    global LETTER_SCORES 
    LETTER_SCORES = {letter: score for score, letters in SCRABBLES_SCORES
             for letter in letters.split()}

    def word_from_score(self,score):
        print(random.choices([word for word in self.file if sum([LETTER_SCORES[letter] for letter in word ]) == score]))
```

And this method returns the word, but doesnt handle the error. So I tried this:

```
def word_from_score(self,score):
    print(random.choices([(word if sum([LETTER_SCORES[letter] for letter in word ]) == score else "") for word in self.file]))
```

But in this case, it returns "" for every argument I pass. Where is mistake in this method?

[EDIT] For example, I run my program from command line and:

```
python main.py -f
```

returns 97, because this is a score for some words in file. So if I run my other method:

```
pythom main.py -s 97
```

Which return the word from file, which has this amount of score. And it works. But if I tak 98 as argument, it wont work, because in file tere is no word with this score. And now I want to handle this case, to return ""

Comment: @timgeb edited again. I didnt add method which is executed by -f param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your list compression is building a list of words that match the score, but that also includes empty strings for any words that don't match the score. You want something like this:

```
def word_from_score(self,score):
    valid_words = [word for word in self.file if sum([LETTER_SCORES[letter] for letter in word ]) == score]
    if len(valid_words) != 0:
        print(random.choices(valid_words))
    else:
        print('')
```